# How to decode the wav file from s3 using node.js fs, wav-decoder

Tags: node.js, wav, fs

I am working with wav file. I could able to decode the wav file from node.js server using fs, wav-decoder.

I need to decode the wav file from s3 storage wav file.

I am facing the no such file/directory error when am trying to decode the s3 wav file using wav-decode and fs.

Please help to solve this issue.

```
var fs=require('fs');
var wav-decoder=require('wav-decoder');

readFile = function(filepath) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fs.readFile(filepath, function(err, buffer)  {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        return reject(err);
      }
      else{
          console.log(buffer);
      return resolve(buffer);
  }
    });
  });
};

var filepath=URL;
        readFile(filepath).then(function(buffer) {
  return WavDecoder.decode(buffer);
}).then(function(audioData) {

  console.log(audioData.sampleRate);
  console.log(audioData.channelData[0]);
```

Comment: Can you provide your code on "trying to decode the s3 wav file using wav-decode and fs"?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to open an url using the `fs` module. Instead, stream the file from s3 using `aws-sdk`. pipe it to `WavDecoder`